# File socket I/O using UDP with Boost ASIO

Tags: c++, boost, udp, boost-asio

So I'm trying to use boost.log with the syslog sink on my FreeBSD servers, which run rsyslogd and listen on a file socket for UDP data. Apparently this works in FreeBSD land. Indeed the file socket is a dgram socket (telnet to a file socket is another thing which works in FreeBSD):

```
$ telnet /var/run/log
Trying /var/run/log...
/var/run/log: Protocol wrong type for socket
```

At any rate, boost.log will not communicate with a file socket, only with an IP address. My plan is to proxy information between a regular IP-based UDP server which my application relays to the file socket. In theory, this should work fine.

However, I cannot find any way to get ASIO to communicate over UDP with a file socket, or even a file socket at all. I understand there may be ways of working with file I/O using ASIO, but this seems to be a hard Google search - nothing relevant comes up. Only a few things (on this very site) which have to deal with Windows file I/O and ASIO, at best.

Ideally, I'd be looking for something like this (though this doesn't exist at all):

```
socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(data, length),
               boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::file_address("/var/run/log"), port);
```

But I'll take anything that'll work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`local::datagram_protocol::endpoint`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/local__datagram_protocol/endpoint.html) and [`local::datagram_protocol::socket`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/local__datagram_protocol/socket.html).